# Python Seaborn Double Plots Appearing

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In short: I have two plots popping up, one empty, then other without the necessary changes and I don't see why.

In long (but relevant info only): I am plotting a polar plot which then needs to be overlayed on an image. The plotting is going relatively well, but I cannot customize the size of the resulting graph as it pops open two plots when the code runs.

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15.3, 15.3)
ax= plt.gca()
ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
fg = sb.FacetGrid(df_plot,subplot_kws=dict(projection='polar'), height=50, aspect = 1.65, sharex=False, sharey=False, despine=False,hue='dot_col', hue_order=_col_ord)
fg.set(ylim=(0, 765))
fg.map_dataframe(sb.scatterplot, x='eval_y', y='dim_x', edgecolor='b')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `sns.FacetGrid` always creates a new figure, ignoring a previously created figure. You can use e.g. `fg.fig.set_size_inches(...)` to customize the FacetGrid, but only after it has been created.  You can probably simplify your code if you don't create a FacetGrid and only call `sns.scatterplot(..., ax=ax)`.

Comment: Also, using `sns.FacetGrid` is deprecated. Instead, use `sns.relplot` with `kind='scatter'`

Comment: that did it, thanks. moving the fg and ax to after fixed the problem. I couldnt get the scatterplot into polar and reverted back to facetgrid for the time being

Thanks both